# Accessing previous responses in Google forms

Tags: google-forms

I am building a survey to help plan a holiday potluck.  I would like to be able to show people who are completing the survey how many dishes of different types (e.g., main, appetizer) and their characteristics (e.g. vegetarian, dairy free) have already been committed.

Is it possible to display summaries of previous responses in a form?

Comment: Would you please provide an example of how you might expect to display this information, the format of the relevant questions regarding selections of dishes and characteristics, whether there are other questions on the form, and the frequency of submissions.

Comment: Just to clarify a basic issue, Google Forms does NOT support real-time update of data from any source, including from the Forms itself, prior to Form Submission. There _is_ a feature to share `previous responses` but this is not available until **after** a respondent completes the form. Also, it shares **ALL** responses which may be inconsistent with privacy considerations. OTOH, Forms has a question-type of `ImageItem` and an (untested) workaround might be to update this image after each submission-the image being a spreadsheet created summary of the meal choices and options count.